# Cucumber '@allow-rescue' tag not working

Tags: java, exception, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have a java cucumber(version 1.1.8) acceptance tests that uses [shazamcrest](https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest) for assertion.
Shazamcrest throws `org.junit.ComparisonFailure` in case of a mismatch so that the IDE can display the difference between the two objects in a nice diff window.

Cucumber on the other hand catches all the Throwables thrown during the test execution and prevent this `Errors`/`Throwables` from reaching the IDE, hence not getting the diff window from the IDE.

I have read that you can add the tag `@allow-rescue` in your scenarios to prevent this from happen, but this is not helping... Cucumbers still catches all my `Errors` and `Exceptions`.

This is the structure of my feature file :

```
@allow-rescue
Feature: feature descrioption

Scenario: scenario
```

According to the docs, scenarios inherits all tags from the Feature.
Can someone please tell me if there is something I am doing wrong or if there is another way to overcome this issue.